# What does 'qualified' mean in 'import qualified Data.List' statement?

Tags: haskell

I understand `import Data.List`.

But what does `qualified` mean in the statement `import qualified Data.List`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A qualified import makes the imported entities available only in qualified form, e.g.

```
import qualified Data.List

result :: [Int]
result = Data.List.sort [3,1,2,4]
```

With just `import Data.List`, the entities are available in qualified form and in unqualified form. Usually, just doing a qualified import leads to too long names, so you

```
import qualified Data.List as L

result :: [Int]
result = L.sort [3,1,2,4]
```

A qualified import allows using functions with the same name imported from several modules, e.g. `map` from the `Prelude` and `map` from `Data.Map`.

Answer (score 48):

If you do an unqualified import (the default), you can refer to anything imported just by its name.

If you do a qualified import, you have to prefix the name with the module it's imported from.

E.g.,

```
import Data.List (sort)
```

This is an unqualified import. You can now say either `sort` or `Data.List.sort`.

```
import qualified Data.List (sort)
```

This is a qualified import. Now `sort` by itself doesn't work, and you have to say `Data.List.sort`.

Because that's quite lengthy, normally you say something like

```
import qualified Data.List (sort) as LS
```

and now you can write `LS.sort`, which is shorter.

Answer (score 17):

The keyword `qualified` means that symbols in the imported modules are not imported into the unqualified (prefixless) namespace. They are only available with their full qualified name. For instance, `foldr'` has the unqualified name `foldr'` and the qualified name `Data.List.foldr'`.

One uses qualified imports to prevent namespace pollution. It is also possible to use `import qualified Foo as Bar`, which imports from `Foo` but with names as if the import stems from `Bar`. For instance, if you type `import qualified Data.List as L`, you can use `foldr'` as `L.foldr'`.