# Haskell - Parallel word count using mapreduce framework (Control.Parallel.Strategies) from Real World Haskell

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I am a student doing an assignment on Parallelism and Concurrency in Haskell. As part of the assignment we were given this code (which is originally from chapter 24 of Real World Haskell) and we were asked to take it and write a parallel word count program:

```
-- file: ch24/MapReduce.hs
mapReduce
    :: Strategy b    -- evaluation strategy for mapping
    -> (a -> b)      -- map function
    -> Strategy c    -- evaluation strategy for reduction
    -> ([b] -> c)    -- reduce function
    -> [a]           -- list to map over
    -> c

-- file: ch24/MapReduce.hs
mapReduce mapStrat mapFunc reduceStrat reduceFunc input =
    mapResult `pseq` reduceResult
  where mapResult    = parMap mapStrat mapFunc input
        reduceResult = reduceFunc mapResult `using` reduceStrat
```

**Sequential version:**

I wrote a sequential version of the program, which works:

```
import System.Environment  
import System.IO  
import System.Directory 
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.List (sort, group)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&)) 
import Data.Map as Map

simpleMapReduce
    :: (a -> b)      -- map function
    -> ([b] -> c)    -- reduce function
    -> [a]           -- list to map over
    -> c             -- result
simpleMapReduce mapFunc reduceFunc  = reduceFunc . Prelude.map mapFunc  

stringToWordCountMap :: String -> Map.Map String Int
stringToWordCountMap  = Map.fromList . Prelude.map (head &&& length) . group . sort . words . Prelude.map toLower 

combineWordCountMaps :: Map.Map String Int -> Map.Map String Int -> Map.Map String Int
combineWordCountMaps map1 map2 = Map.unionWith (+) map1 map2

reduceWordCountMaps :: [Map.Map String Int] -> Map.Map String Int
reduceWordCountMaps  (x:[]) = x
reduceWordCountMaps (x:xs) = combineWordCountMaps x (reduceWordCountMaps xs)

main = do (fileName:_) <- getArgs  
          fileExists <- doesFileExist fileName  
          if fileExists  
              then do contents <- readFile fileName  
                  let fileInLines = lines contents
              result = simpleMapReduce stringToWordCountMap reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines
                      putStrLn $ "The file has " ++ show (length (lines contents)) ++ " lines!"
              putStrLn $ "result = " ++ show result ++ "."

              else do putStrLn "The file doesn't exist!"
```

And at the moment I am trying to figure out how to get this to work in parallell using the framework given.

**What I have done so far:**

This is my attempt at writing a parallel version of the above, which I cannot even get to compile:

*(I'm using ghc -threaded -rts opts -eventlog part02.hs)*

```
import System.Environment  
import System.IO
import System.Directory 
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.List (sort, group)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&)) 
import Data.Map as Map
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

mapReduce
    :: Strategy b    -- evaluation strategy for mapping
    -> (a -> b)      -- map function
    -> Strategy c    -- evaluation strategy for reduction
    -> ([b] -> c)    -- reduce function
    -> [a]           -- list to map over
    -> c

-- file: ch24/MapReduce.hs
mapReduce mapStrat mapFunc reduceStrat reduceFunc input =
    mapResult `pseq` reduceResult
  where mapResult    = Control.Parallel.Strategies.parMap mapStrat mapFunc input
        reduceResult = reduceFunc mapResult `using` reduceStrat

stringToWordCountMap :: String -> Map.Map String Int
stringToWordCountMap  = Map.fromList . Prelude.map (head &&& length) . group . sort . words . Prelude.map toLower 

combineWordCountMaps :: Map.Map String Int -> Map.Map String Int -> Map.Map String Int
combineWordCountMaps map1 map2 = Map.unionWith (+) map1 map2

reduceWordCountMaps :: [ Map.Map String Int] -> Map.Map String Int
reduceWordCountMaps  (x:[]) = x
reduceWordCountMaps  (x:xs) = combineWordCountMaps x (reduceWordCountMaps xs)

main = do (fileName:_) <- getArgs  
          fileExists <- doesFileExist fileName  
          if fileExists  
              then do contents <- readFile fileName  
                  let fileInLines = lines contents
              result = mapReduce Control.Parallel.Strategies.parMap stringToWordCountMap Control.Parallel.Strategies.parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines

                      putStrLn $ "The file has " ++ show (length (lines contents)) ++ " lines!"
              putStrLn $ "result = " ++ show result ++ "."
              else do putStrLn "The file doesn't exist!"
```

**edit -** Compiler error message:

```
part02.hs:43:46:
    Couldn't match type `(a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]'
                  with `Eval (Strategy b0)'
    Expected type: Strategy (Strategy b0)
      Actual type: Strategy b0 -> (a0 -> b0) -> [a0] -> [b0]
    In the first argument of `mapReduce', namely `parMap'
    In the expression:
      mapReduce
        parMap stringToWordCountMap parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines
    In an equation for `result':
        result
          = mapReduce
              parMap stringToWordCountMap parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLine
s

part02.hs:43:81:
    Couldn't match type `Map String Int' with `b0 -> Eval b0'
    Expected type: String -> Strategy b0
      Actual type: String -> Map String Int
    In the second argument of `mapReduce', namely
      `stringToWordCountMap'
    In the expression:
      mapReduce
        parMap stringToWordCountMap parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines
    In an equation for `result':
        result
          = mapReduce
              parMap stringToWordCountMap parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLine
s

part02.hs:43:102:
    Couldn't match type `[a1] -> Eval [a1]' with `Eval (Strategy a1)'
    Expected type: Strategy (Strategy a1)
      Actual type: Strategy a1 -> Strategy [a1]
    In the third argument of `mapReduce', namely `parList'
    In the expression:
      mapReduce
        parMap stringToWordCountMap parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines
    In an equation for `result':
        result
          = mapReduce
              parMap stringToWordCountMap parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLine
s

part02.hs:43:138:
    Couldn't match type `Map String Int' with `b0 -> Eval b0'
    Expected type: [Strategy b0] -> Strategy a1
      Actual type: [Map String Int] -> Map String Int
    In the fourth argument of `mapReduce', namely `reduceWordCountMaps'
    In the expression:
      mapReduce
        parMap stringToWordCountMap parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines
    In an equation for `result':
        result
          = mapReduce
              parMap stringToWordCountMap parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLine
s
```

I was wondering if it would be possible for anyone to have a look at this and help me get this to work? I am still not very experienced with haskell so apologies if I am missing something obvious. I am finding the Strategies a bit confusing so any links / resources would be appreciated too. Thanks very much.

**Final edit:**

From user5402's answer:

> I also got some indentation errors when I copied-pasted your code. A version which only gives warnings is available here.

Just pasted this below in case it disappears:

```
import System.Environment  
import System.IO
import System.Directory 
import Data.Char (toLower)
import Data.List (sort, group)
import Control.Arrow ((&&&)) 
import Data.Map as Map
import Control.Parallel
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

mapReduce
    :: Strategy b    -- evaluation strategy for mapping
    -> (a -> b)      -- map function
    -> Strategy c    -- evaluation strategy for reduction
    -> ([b] -> c)    -- reduce function
    -> [a]           -- list to map over
    -> c

-- file: ch24/MapReduce.hs
mapReduce mapStrat mapFunc reduceStrat reduceFunc input =
    mapResult `pseq` reduceResult
  where mapResult    = parMap mapStrat mapFunc input
        reduceResult = reduceFunc mapResult `using` reduceStrat

stringToWordCountMap :: String -> Map.Map String Int
stringToWordCountMap  = Map.fromList . Prelude.map (head &&& length) . group . sort . words . Prelude.map toLower 

combineWordCountMaps :: Map.Map String Int -> Map.Map String Int -> Map.Map String Int
combineWordCountMaps map1 map2 = Map.unionWith (+) map1 map2

reduceWordCountMaps :: [ Map.Map String Int] -> Map.Map String Int
reduceWordCountMaps  (x:[]) = x
reduceWordCountMaps  (x:xs) = combineWordCountMaps x (reduceWordCountMaps xs)

main = do (fileName:_) <- getArgs  
          fileExists <- doesFileExist fileName  
          if fileExists  
              then do contents <- readFile fileName  
                      let fileInLines = lines contents
                          result = mapReduce rpar stringToWordCountMap rpar reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines

                      putStrLn $ "The file has " ++ show (length (lines contents)) ++ " lines!"
                      putStrLn $ "result = " ++ show result ++ "."
              else do putStrLn "The file doesn't exist!"
```

Comment: "This is my attempt at writing a parallel version of the above, which I cannot even get to compile." What error message do you get?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I get this (very long) error message:

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I get a very long error message that I've added to the question. The code I posted was really the result of me trying a bunch of things however, I don't really think it SHOULD work as it is at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
result = mapReduce Control.Parallel.Strategies.parMap stringToWordCountMap Control.Parallel.Strategies.parList reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines
```

for a `Strategy` you should provide a value like `rpar` or `rseq`. See [this documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.1.0.1/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#g:4) for other defined strategies. So the above line should look like:

```
result = mapReduce rpar stringToWordCountMap rpar reduceWordCountMaps fileInLines
```

I also got some indentation errors when I copied-pasted your code. A version which only gives warnings is available [here](http://lpaste.net/114974).

Note: There is no need to fully qualify the names `parMap`, `rpar`, etc. If there are conflicts, consider using [qualified imports with abbreviations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11274895/866915).

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your answer, apologies for not responding until now. I just tried that and that worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!