# What is the difference between qualified and unqualified imports in the new javascript ES6 module lingo?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

I came across this distinction which wasn't explained well in [ExploringJS](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)

> Qualified and unqualified imports work the same way (they are both indirections)

What is the distinction and therefore what does this statement mean?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274864/what-does-qualified-mean-in-import-qualified-data-list-statement), which explains the concept of qualified vs. unqualified imports in Haskell (this concept carries over to ES6). TL;DR, qualified imports require that you specify the name of the module containing a function when you call an imported function.

Comment: I searched Stack Overflow with "unqualified javascript" because of exactly the same sentence in the same book which, as Arijit states, is not well explained. I appreciate the comment from @Jules that re-directs to another answer, but I don't want to have mentally parse Haskell or any other language to understand these concepts in JavaScript. Having read that other answer, I _think_ it has something to do with named vs default exports leading to qualified vs unqualified imports, but any clarification/correction/expansion would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, there's no such thing as qualified/unqualified imports in JavaScrpit. Those terms were used in the book 'Exploring ES6' by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer in the context of cyclic dependencies, and roughly mean:

##### Unqualified imports (directly import a part of a module):

CommonJS:

```
var foo = require('a').foo // doesn't work with cyclic dependencies
```

ES2015:

```
import {foo} from 'a' // can work with cyclic dependencies*
```

##### Qualified imports (import the whole module as a namespace):

CommonJS:

```
var a = require('a')
function bar() {
  a.foo() // can work with cyclic dependencies*
}
exports.bar = bar
```

ES2015:

```
import * as a from 'a'
export function bar() {
  a.foo() // can work with cyclic dependencies*
}
```

In ES2015 default imports can also be qualified imports (although some people disagree) if they serve as a namespace:

```
export default {
  fn1,
  fn2
}
```

with cyclic dependencies, you can't access imports in the body of a module:

```
import {foo} from 'a' // 'a' is a cyclic dependency
foo() // doesn't work
```

Comment: No, a default-exported object is not qualified.